# Get a tree like structure out of path string

Tags: recursion, go, tree

I am stuck since 2 days, as I am not to firm with pointers and recursion. I have an array of path like structures, lets say:

```
s:=[]string {
  "a/b/c",
  "a/b/g",
  "a/d",
}
```

With a data structure like this:

```
 type Node struct {
   Name     string `json:"name"`
   Children []Node `json:"children"`
}
```

I would like to end up with something like this:

```
{
 "name": "a",
 "children": [
     {
      "name": "b",
      "children": [
        {
         "name": "c",
         "children": []
        },
        {
         "name": "g",
         "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
     "name": "d",
     "children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to build it with a recursion, which works kind of fine, but only for one string (e.g. "a/b/c"), as soon as I try to implement something which should add missing nodes ("g" in "a/b/g") to a tree I am stuck.

I had something like:

```
func appendChild(root Node, children []string) Node {
   if len(children) == 1 {
      return Node{children[0], nil}
   } else {
      t := root
      t.Name=children[0]
      t.Children = append(t.Children, appendChild(root, children[1:]))
      return t
   }
}
```

Could someone point me to an efficient solution?

Comment: You can do a google search for a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or [Radix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) insertion algorithm to get an idea on how to implement what you want.

Comment: you can post similar question like this to codereview.stackexchange if you have no issue but wanted to improve your solution

Comment: Actually the code is not really working, but I will try your suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://play.golang.org/p/9pER5cwChF

```
func AddToTree(root []Node, names []string) []Node {
    if len(names) > 0 {
        var i int
        for i = 0; i < len(root); i++ {
            if root[i].Name == names[0] { //already in tree
                break
            }
        }
        if i == len(root) {
            root = append(root, Node{Name: names[0]})
        }
        root[i].Children = AddToTree(root[i].Children, names[1:])
    }
    return root
}
```

Example output (note that I used `omitempty` on the children field, because I don't like `null` entries in my JSONs):

```
[{
    "name": "a",
    "children": [{
        "name": "b",
        "children": [{
            "name": "c"
        }, {
            "name": "g"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "d"
    }]
}]
```

Notable difference from your version:

- It operates on a list of nodes instead of the children of a single node.  This is important, as your version assumes that all of the trees have the same single root node (`a`), when this might not be the case.  The only way to handle that in your version is to have a "fake" node at the root.
- It does NOT reuse the input node.  This is one of the primary problems with your code.  If len(children) > 1, you update the input node's name, append to it's children, then recurse.  This means that every prior level of the slice becomes part of the children.  You need to create a *new* node instead.
- It actually searches the tree.  You're not searching the tree to see if the item being inserted already exists, so you duplicate nodes (specifically, node b)